# APA bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Good day!

I need a help with APA bibliograpy style for submitting my article to Expert Systems with Applications (Elsevier).

I need a (Smith, 2020) style of citation. But I'm able just to get Smith (2020) by the following code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{apa}\biboptions{authoryear,sort,comma}

\begin{document}

..., see \cite{cjm-ex'17}, \cite{gonzalez'18},  \cite{cjm'17}, \cite{xin'18},  \cite{wei}, \cite{liu'13}, \cite{vaganov'17}. 


\bibliography{mybibfile}{}

\end{document}
```

What should I change?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se  You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon. Are you sure you can use `biblatex` for your submission? Few journals at the moment are using it. So I would check that first. Also you are using a mixture of `natbib` and `biblatex` commands which won't work. So I think you first need to determined whether you can use `biblatex` before we give you a solution to your problem that won't actually be usable.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "APA bibliograpy style". For sure, the APA's own definition of "APA style" has evolved significantly over the years. The `apa` and `apalike` bibliography styles date back to the 1980s and definitely do *not* come close to implementing current APA style guidelines. Or do you maybe use the term APA bibliograpy style as a synonym for author-year citation style? (You wouldn't be the first to do so...) Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reaction to my question! That is what I have from editor: "Reference Style:
Citations in the text should follow the referencing style used by the American Psychological Association. ... APA's in-text citations require the author's last name and the year of publication. You should cite publications in the text, for example, (Smith, 2020).  However, you should not use [Smith, 2020]." There are also several requirements for Reference List organisation, that I don't know how to do with usual BibTeX.

Comment: I'don't think that it worth using BibLatex, if it is so rare at the moment. But I would need to find a way how to correct my Reference Style and Reference List according with the journal requirements. Up to now, I'm familiar just with usual BibTeX, [1], [2], etc. :)

Comment: Here are examples of references from the journal: (Strnad, & Kohek, 2017), (Kohek et al., 2015, Kolmanič et al., 2017), (Allen et al., 2005, Balandier et al., 2000, Fišer et al., 2015, Kang et al., 2016, Lescourret et al., 2011, Xia et al., 2009).  I need to do in the same manner...

Comment: Then I would recommend @mico 's answer to this question: [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812). For citation lists inside parentheses, use `\citep{key1, key2, key3 ...}` which yields "(Auhor, year; Author, year ...)" instead of `\cite{key1}`, which yields "Author (year)"

Comment: Do you mean that I need to use
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}.  ?

Comment: @user225939 - Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your editor's instructions, *viz.*,

> Reference Style: Citations in the text should follow the referencing style used by the American Psychological Association ... APA's in-text citations require the author's last name and the year of publication. You should cite publications in the text, for example, (Smith, 2020). ...

lead me to infer that all the editor really requires is that you generate parenthetic-style citation call-outs, of the form `(Smith, 2020)`. (Aside: The APA generally requires authoryear-style citation call-outs. However, there's *a lot more* to "APA style" than just the appearance of the citation call-outs.)

If this piece of inference is correct and if you wish to (or need to) use the `elsarticle` document class, then all you need to do, in terms of document setup, is (a) specify the option `authoryear` at the `\documentclass` stage, (b) run the instruction `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}`, and use `\citep` instructions to create the citation call-outs. Why? Because the `elsarticle` document class loads the `natbib` citation management package automatically and because most Elsevier journals that require authoryear-style citation call-outs also require the use of the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style.

The following outline should work for you. Observe that it's possible to pass multiple arguments to `\citep`, as long as the arguments are separated by commas.

```
\documentclass[review,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\begin{document}
... \citep[see][]{cjm-ex:17,gonzalez:18,cjm:17,xin:18,wei-liu:13,vaganov:17}. 
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try this variant. Though it seems that I managed with (Smith,2020) by using \citep{} in the code:

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}                                                                                           
\usepackage[american]{babel}                  
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{apa}\biboptions{authoryear,sort,comma}   
 \begin{document}
... \citep{cjm-ex:17,gonzalez:18,cjm:17,xin:18,wei-liu:13,vaganov:17}. 
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This may well be what the journal expects, but the `apa` bibliography style does not implement the actual APA style, just a rough approximation of it. Unfortunately "APA style" is often used simply to mean "author-year".  See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793).